# Can single maximal fraction be increased by one-party local operation?

Tags: quantum-information

For a quantum channel $\Lambda$, the corresponding bipartite state
is $\rho=(I\otimes\Lambda)(|\Phi\rangle\langle\Phi|)$, where $|\Phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i}|ii\rangle$.

The maximal singlet fraction is defined as $f(\rho)=Max_{\psi}\langle\psi|\rho|\psi\rangle$.
where $\psi$ is maximal entangled state.

If the second system passes another quantum channel,

$\rho'=(I\otimes\Lambda')\rho$

Is it true that $f(\rho)\geq f(\rho')$? How to prove it?